# angular src working fine with relative path, but not ng-src

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

Within a directive, I am using the angular ng-include with the src attribute like this:

```
template: '<div ng-include src="\'app/views/address_detail_view.html\' "></div>' +...
```

This works ok.

Now using the exact same statement with the ng-src instead of src:

```
template: '<div ng-include ng-src="\'app/views/address_detail_view.html\' "></div>' +...
```

Then the inclusion does not work. Nothing happens, no exceptions are raised.

My final goal is to include a var within the src (or ng-src) attribute, but if I do this:

```
template: '<div ng-include src="{{myVar}}' "></div>' +...
```

then I get the exception: [object XrayWrapper [object DOMException]]

NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

This is why I am striving to make the ng-src work but it doesn't seem to find my relative url.

Any ideas why ng-src isn't working or should i file a bug to the angular team?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs

[image: ngInclude Arguments]

You can see that the src attribute is actually expecting an "angular expression." Meaning the src attribute needs no `{{myVar}}` style syntax. Instead if you have a scope var `myVar` present in the directive scope when you instantiate the directive the value of myVar will be placed in the src.

`<div ng-include src="myVar"></div>`

So in your case:

```
return {
    link:function($scope) {
        $scope.myVar = 'x.html';
    },
    template: '<div ng-include src="myVar' "></div>' +...
}
```